# What is this access line of code in my Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have the following in my controller but I don't know what the `access` line means. I'm new to Rails 4. Is it for some gem like devise or something? I've looked through Google and don't see any documentation for the second line here. Any help would be great!

```
class MyCoolController < ApplicationController
    access user: :all, all: [:my_action_name]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ask Ruby where the method was defined by booting your application / loading that controller with some debugging inserted:

```
class MyCoolController < ApplicationController
  p method(:access).source_location
```

Comment: Or just `MyCoolController.method(:access)` from the console.